# Reading and comparing strings in a text file, variables not initialized

Tags: java, file-io

I'm getting the error

> the local variables name and password may not have been initialized,

for the if-statement. These errors go away if I change the second string in parentheses to something in quotes, or if I set the variables to 0, but then I would also need to change them to `int` and I need them to be `String`.

I'm trying to compare the username and password from a text file to a newly input username and password. The program should also quit after 3 bad attempts so I probably put the `System.out.println("Goodbye!");` in the wrong place too.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int numberOfAttempts = 1;
        String fileName = "logins.txt";
        Scanner inputStream = null;
        String name, password, line, secondname;
        String secondpassword;


        do
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter your username: ");
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            secondname = keyboard.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter your password: ");
            secondpassword = keyboard.nextLine();
            try
            {
                inputStream = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Error opening the file " + 
                        fileName);
                System.exit(0);
            }
            while (inputStream.hasNextLine())
               {
                   line = inputStream.nextLine();
               }
            if ((name.equalsIgnoreCase(secondname))&&
                    (password.equalsIgnoreCase(secondpassword)))
            {System.out.println("Welcome!");
            numberOfAttempts = 4;
            }

            else
                System.out.println("Invalid. Please try again.");
            numberOfAttempts++;

        }

        while ( numberOfAttempts <4);
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");


        inputStream.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: Set your Strings to "" And then concatenate the data? When the if statement tries to compare your name or password variable, it hasn't gotten a value assigned to these for it to even compare anything. What is the value of name and password supposed to be? You have to assign something to them.

Answer (score 1):

You never initialize `name` and `password`, so of course you'll get this error.

You initialize `secondname` and `secondpassword`, but your condition checks `name` and `password` which are not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

In JAVA methods, any local variable must be initialized first it can be used. In your case you are trying to compare the name &  password in your code are never initialized or assigned a value.. It will be a good idea to initialize your strings either as NULL or empty string such as "" or any desired value.

Comment: thank you! this solved my problem with the errors. but as user deong mentioned, I'm unable to compare the strings since everything read from the txt file is being thrown away. do you know how to fix that? my java book is extremely unhelpful

Comment: When a resolution helps you , then you can upvote and accept it confirm it to other users that this a valid resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bunch of problems.

The errors are caused by the fact that you never assign any values to the variables "name" and "password", but you then check to see if those variables match the secondname and secondpassword variables you do read. Because name and password never get any values at all, the comparison can't possibly be what you intend, so the compiler flags it as an error.

You can make the error go away by assigning name and password to some values when you declare them, but your program still isn't going to work correctly, because no matter what value you assign, it probably won't be the thing that the user of your program would want to be comparing against.

Presumably your intent is to read the value of name and password from the input file you've opened and read in, but in fact you aren't doing anything with the values in that file except immediately throwing them away. Look at the loop

```
while(inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
    line = inputStream.nextLine();
}
```

This loop will read in every line from the file, but as soon as you read one line, you throw away whatever you read into the line variable because you have to reuse that variable to read the next line, which you'll also throw away immediately. At the end of the loop, you'll have saved the last line from the file into `line`, but the rest of the program doesn't use the `line` variable either.

You need to put some logic inside that loop to read whatever you wanted to read from the file, store it in the name and password variables, and then you'll have some hope that when you do the equalsIgnoreCase stuff that you'll actually be comparing variables that have some meaning to your program.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. i understand why it's not working now but i don't know how to fix it. my java book doesn't go over this. can you help at all? it would be much appreciated.